# Flutter "Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results." error

Tags: flutter

Before upgrading Flutter version to 3.16.0, everything was working. Previous version: 3.10. After the upgrade, I started getting errors in many plugins. When I want to run the project on iOS, I get an error.

Flutter Doctor :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on macOS 14.1.1 23B81 darwin-arm64, locale en-TR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.2.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Log output:

```
Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' to '/Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' to '/Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex'


Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/_CodeSignature ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:CodeSign /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app ->

node: /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalCore.framework/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

directoryContents: /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalCore.framework ->

node: /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalCore.framework ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks /Users/mcl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cxfddsvrsqgujgfzuetkmcgoizkf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-EADB2FCD36FF1A52BC52ED37.sh ->

node: /Users/mcl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cxfddsvrsqgujgfzuetkmcgoizkf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/InputFileList-EADB2FCD36FF1A52BC52ED37-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-47ee6d0f4dc80edbab304614a43967ec-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/mcl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cxfddsvrsqgujgfzuetkmcgoizkf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/InputFileList-EADB2FCD36FF1A52BC52ED37-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-47ee6d0f4dc80edbab304614a43967ec-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node: <target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5-copy-files> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5-copy-files ->

node: <Copy /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex> ->

CYCLE POINT ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex ->

node: <target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase4-thin-binary> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase4-thin-binary ->

node: <execute-shell-script-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e02f1eee2015e8ff5ebcd27678f788c2826-target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-> ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution Thin Binary /Users/mcl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cxfddsvrsqgujgfzuetkmcgoizkf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh ->

node: /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: q ->

directoryContents: /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist /Users/mcl/projectx/ios/Runner/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex /Users/mcl/projectx/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
```

Thank you from now.

I did the following:
flutter upgrade, flutter clean & flutter pub get.
I deleted Podfile.lock in the ios folder and did pod install --repo-update.
but it didn't work at all

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue